# LuaJIT error with Embarcadero C++Builder XE5

Tags: c++, lua, c++builder, luajit, c++builder-xe5

I've compiled the latest **LuaJIT** version using both MinGW32 and MSVC32,
and then created an import lib using Embarcadero's implib tool:

```
implib -a lua51.lib lua51.dll
```

The library is linked with sample C++ program and compiled with the bcc32 compiler.

Everything that worked with vanilla Lua 5.1 works fine with LuaJIT (much faster of course), but the problem arises with **FFI**.

Here is a simple C function inside of my C++ code:

```
// header
extern "C"  {
  int test_ffi(int value);
  }
// cpp file
int test_ffi(int value) {
   int xx = value + 1;
   return xx;
}
```

test.lua file:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[int test_ffi(int value);]]
local a = 100
local C = ffi.C
local result = C.test_ffi(a)
```

CPP execution part:

```
//...
lua_State *L =  luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)test_ffi);
luaJIT_setmode(L, -1, LUAJIT_MODE_WRAPCFUNC|LUAJIT_MODE_ON);
lua_pop(L, 1);
int result;
result = luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua");
if (result == 0)
   result = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
lua_close(L);
//...
```

When `lua_pcall()` is executed, it calls `test_ffi()` as expected, but the value passed to the function is not 100, but some *uninitialized* random value. The result from `lua_pcall()` is 2.

I've tried various calling conventions (`__cdecl`, `__stdcall`) but no effect.

Also, replacing the MSVC32 DLLs with MinGW32 DLLs produces the same result.

When some `void` function is called, `lua_pcall()` produces an Access Violation in `lua51.dll`. I know that LuaJIT does not officially support bcc32 compilers, but except for FFI, all other APIs work correctly.

Does anyone have any clue what is happening?

Comment: That's not a C function, but a C++ function with C linkage.

Comment: Yes I know that. What I don't understand is the point of your remark.

Comment: ```lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)test_ffi);
luaJIT_setmode(L, -1, LUAJIT_MODE_WRAPCFUNC|LUAJIT_MODE_ON);
lua_pop(L, 1);```

Remove this.

Comment: That's fair, I don't understand why you added a tag for a different, unrelated language.

Comment: Well, it's my first post/question on stackoverflow. This post should be related to lua/luajit with Embarcadero C++. Should I remove C++ tag?